# Adobe Premiere Pro Green Lines Problem

Tags: premiere

Can you please help me to fix this?

[image]

How can I remove these green lines from my video preview in Premiere Pro 2020?

Comment: Is this only happening with that one video, with multiple videos that have something in common, or with every video?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when i updated my graphics driver, I use Windows 10, Intel i3 8th Gen. Version which did the problem was 27.20.100.8336.
you need Intel Graphics - BETA Windows 10 DCH Driver
Windows 10, 64-bit version 27.20.100.8425
link to update your driver https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/80939/Graphics